# Why is ProtoBuf-Net's performance so poor when serializing a list of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, compression, protobuf-net

I'm playing around with ProtoBuf, trying to get an idea of what kind of compression to expect. As a test case, I've got a list of 10,000,000 ten character strings and I'm serializing and then splitting it into 3.9mb chunks. ProtoBuf seems to do a horrible job of this and ends up creating over 30 chunks. Here are the results of the tests I've run.

---

ProtoBuf-Net Serialization: 30 3.9mb chunks

BinaryFormatter Serialization: 12 3.9mb chunks

BinaryFormatter w/Deflate Stream Serialization: 1 72kb chunk

---

I am calling ProtoBuf like so:

```
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<List<string>>(names);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 10 million 10-char strings take 10E6*(4+10*2) = 229 MB = 59 chunks.  Cutting that by a factor of 2 is pretty simple by using an 8-bit encoding.  That glass is half-full.

Comment: @Hans protobuf uses UTF-8, so I can deduce that the strings are basically ASCII-range - 30 chunks is about right for raw data plus overhead. It can be optimised, of course (discussed in my answer)

Comment: elicid, next time use your calculator so we don't have to. 30*3.9MB/10000000=12 bytes per 10-character string. That size sounds perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you indicate what the test data is here? I suspect that you are serializing the same string instances multiple times. BinaryFormatter always reuses references. The core protobuf specification has no object re-use, so protobuf-net (for compatibility) respects this - but it does *support* object re-use (with strings special-cased for performance). But it is strictly opt-in, to preserve compatibility with other protobuf implementations.

So: if the data is genuinely going to use the same string contents: I could show you how to enable this.

If the data is **not** genuinely going to use the same string contents: then your test is invalid.

Comment: Marc, that's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks for giving me some insight into how ProtoBuf is working behind the scenes. How would I go about optimizing it as you suggested, though? Now I'm just curious.

Comment: @elucid8 I would need to check, but I *think* this would do it - if not, it might need a separate class: `public class SomeWrapper { [ProtoMember(1, AsReference=true, DataFormat=DataFormat.Group)] public List<string> Items {get;set;} }`